# can instance variable be accessed by sub classes in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I recently started learning ruby . i would like to know what exactly is instance variable in ruby. i have written a small code to learn what instance variable is .

```
class Animal
    def animal_sound
        @sound = "roar"
        @sound + " "+"animal"
    end
end
class Human < Animal
    def human_sound
        @sound + " "+"human"
    end
end
human = Human.new
p human.animal_sound
p human.human_sound
```

output:

```
"roar animal"
"roar human"
```

I know that instance variable belong only to one class and it's sub-classes are separate.But how did my human class was able to access @sound from animal class?

Comment: Insert the line `puts "self in animal_sound=#{self}"` in `animal_sound` and see what happens when you run the code. You may find this technique useful in other cases.

Answer (score 3):

> how did my human class was able to access @sound from animal class?

It didn't. It accessed the *method* (`Animal#animal_sound`), which is inherited. When you did `human.animal_sound`, it attached `@sound` to the current `self`, i.e. `human` -- the instance (not to `Human`, and not to `Animal`). `@sound` does not belong to classes; it belongs to *instances* (which is why it's called an instance variable). Then, `human.human_sound` read `@sound` from the current `self` again, i.e. `human` (not from `Human`, not from `Animal`).

Comment: what u said is correct i think . but i read in ruby for beginners book that  class instance variables belong to  exactly  one class and it's sub classes are separate.

Comment: You are mixing several terms here. Instance variables go on instances; they will always go onto the current instance (`self`), and they can only be accessed by that class (but note that methods inherited from ancestors are also on the current instance's class - that's what inheritance means). Class variables (`@@foo`) go onto classes, and are shared with descendants. Class instance variables are normal instance variables that are accessed by class functions (i.e. where `self` is an instance of the `Class` class). In your post you have instance variable, not class instance variable.

Comment: If you actually *had* a *class instance variable*, that is indeed restricted to belong to one class (because they are on the instance of the `Class`, which is not shared by any other object). If you mix in some functions into the `Class` class, they would be able to access them as well (`class Foo; @bar = 7; end; class Class; def bar; @bar; end; end; Foo.bar` would be such a contrived example) but this is not normally done; so for all practical purposes, class instance variables are only accessible from that class's class methods, as you quote your book saying.

Answer (score 2):

A Ruby instance consists of

1. a collection of instance variables (data)
2. a reference to the type which defines the behavior

In your example, the instance `human` can be interpreted as

```
                                         ...
                                          |
                                        Object { ... }
                                          |
                                        Animal { def animal_sound }
human -----> {@sound}                     |
              <type>  ----------------> Human { def human_sound }
```

Any instance methods (behavior) available on the `human` instance will operate on the same set of instance variables in part 1. In your example, this is `{@sound}`.

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables aren't "inherited" per-se, but since they live in the context of the instance itself they are accessible by *any and all methods* that instance has.

Think of an object as a container that has associated methods and instance variables. You can add, remove, and alter these as you see fit, though normally adding and removing methods is only done once in your class definition. It's just that since Ruby is highly *dynamic*, you can actually do this whenever you want.

For example, here's a rewritten demonstration:

```
class Animal
  def initialize(name = nil)
    # Define a local instance variable that defines their name
    @name = name || 'Betsy'
  end

  def animal_sound
    # Default noise an animal makes
    'moo'
  end

  def sound
    # A more personalized sound effect
    '%s goes %s' % [ @name, animal_sound ]
  end
end

class Human < Animal
  def animal_sound
    # Override the default behaviour based on name
    case (@name)
    when 'Bruce'
      # Where anyone named Bruce does something different
      'yo'
    else
      'rawr'
    end
  end
end

chucky = Human.new('Chucky')

p chucky.sound
# => "Chucky goes rawr"

bruce = Human.new('Bruce')

p bruce.sound
# => "Bruce goes yo"
```

Here `@name` is assigned in the parent class initializer, but it's bound to the instance itself, which is actually of type `Human`, so it's accessible to any methods like `animal_sound` in Human. Note that this works in reverse, too, the parent class is calling `animal_sound` but the one that ends up being used is the subclass version, not the parent's, because the subclass defined different behaviour.

This is the cornerstone of object oriented-programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code doesn't show good use of instance variables... it shows use of instance methods (and inheritance of them from the parent class). An instance variable is a variable that is accessible to just that instance.

Here's an example:

```
class Animal
  def animal_sound
    @sound = "roar"
    @sound + " "+"animal"
  end
  # This reader-method lets us see the value of the @eye_colour instance-variable
  def eye_colour
    "My eyes are: #{@eye_colour}"
  end
  # This writer-method lets us set the value of the @eye_colour instance variable 
  def eye_colour=(new_colour)
    @eye_colour = new_colour
  end
end
class Human < Animal
  def human_sound
    @sound + " "+"human"
  end
  # inherits the colour-methods from Animal
end

# when you create a new instance of human, you can give them an eye-colour
human = Human.new
human.eye_colour = "Green"
human.eye_colour # => "My eyes are: Green"

# if you create a new instance of human, you can give them a different eye colour
human2 = Human.new
human2.eye_colour = "Brown"
human2.eye_colour # => "My eyes are: Brown"

# but the first human is still the original colour - 
# because the variable contains a value just for *that* instance.
# This is what it means to be an instance-variable   
human.eye_colour # => "My eyes are: Green"
```

Comment: "Your example code doesn't show instance variables... "??? `@sound` is an instance variable.

Comment: `@eye_colour` is an instance variable

Comment: They *both* are. Why did you need to introduce a new one, when OP had a perfectly nice one in their question?

Comment: Yes, but the example used to demonstrate `@sound` didn't show the *use* of that instance variable...

Comment: Why introduce a new one? because I felt like it... :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Human` class is inherited from the `Animal` class. So the instance variable `@sound` initiate in `Animal` class is accessable in `Human` class.

Like the sub class inheriting the properties from the parent class.

Comment: Instance variables are not inherited, they are nothing like JavaScript properties (if that is what you are referring to - Ruby doesn't have the term "property", except in ActiveRecord, which are yet another unrelated thing).

Answer (score 0):

Human class is effectively the same as:

```
class Human
  def animal_sound
    @sound = "roar"
    @sound + " " + "animal"
  end

  def human_sound
    @sound + " " + "human"
  end
end
```

For your new instance `human = Human.new`, when you call `animal_sound`, this defines `@sound` for your particular instance `human`.

Because `@sound` is an instance-variable it's available to all other methods available to `human`. That is, `@sound` can be seen in `human_sound` as well.

Notice if you call `human_sound` before `animal_sound`, `@sound` will return `nil` which will result in an error. Since `@sound` is to be used elsewhere it would be reasonable to define it in a special `initialize` method. This way `@sound` is automatically defined as specified for every new instance. 
Now it doesn't matter in which order you call `animal_sound` and `human_sound`.

```
class Human
  def initialize
    @sound = "roar" 
  end

  def animal_sound
    @sound + " " + "animal"
  end

  def human_sound
    @sound + " " + "human"
  end      
end

human = Human.new
human.human_sound  #=> "roar human"
human.animal_sound #=> "roar animal"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that instance variable belong only to one class

No. Instance variables belong to objects (aka instances). That's why they are called *instance* variables, after all.

> But how did my human class was able to access @sound from animal class?

It wasn't. The instance variable belongs to `human`.